# Parallel kernels cannot launch: LinkOpen::linke error

Tags: parallelization, mathlink-or-wstp, kernel-startup

I have been regularly using parallel kernels on my machine but this morning all I receive is a cryptic error whenever I call any parallel function (LinkOpen::linke).

As far as I can see sequential computations are not affected.

My only thought is that the IT people updated some site licences yesterday. But they have not updated the software on the machines yet.

Does anyone have any idea where I can even begin to solve this problem?

```
user@machine:~$ math
Mathematica 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
Copyright 1988-2014 Wolfram Research, Inc.

In[1]:= ParallelEvaluate[$KernelID]                                                                                                                           
Launching kernels...

LinkOpen::linke: Unknown MathLink problem encountered..

LinkOpen::linke: Unknown MathLink problem encountered..

LinkOpen::linke: Unknown MathLink problem encountered..

General::stop: Further output of LinkOpen::linke will be suppressed during this calculation.

SubKernels`LocalKernels`LaunchLocal::somefail: 16 of 16 kernels failed to launch.

Out[1]= {}
```

I am happy to add other details if you can think of any that are relevant.

Answer (score 3):

This was not really a Mathematica problem. The system disc was full. (Zero bytes free.)

Freeing up some space enabled kernel launches to work again.